# How to allow users to save list of posts in wordpress?

Tags: php, posts

I want user to allow to create these types of list. Then they can add any number of posts. And these list are private. I mean only created user and admin can access the list.

[image]

Comment: Is this for logged in users or all site visitors? OK, you'll need to decide how to store these lists (serialized as a user_meta property? Or just a browser cookie?), create the UI for creating / editing / saving them, set up pages or AJAX or REST API endpoints to update the lists, and presumably a page somewhere to view them too? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Or if you search for 'pinterest-like' plugins and themes then there are number of results that might do something like this already. But I haven't looked at any to recommend them.